# querySelector event listener `scroll`

Tags: javascript, html, dom, scroll, dom-events

I am trying to understand why `scroll` event listener of `querySelector` element doesn't work here

```js
document.querySelector('.test-scroll')
  .addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    alert('Scroll');
  }, false);
```

```css
.test-scroll {
  height: 2000px;
  overflow-x: none;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-scroll">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: The scroll bar isn't in the DIV, it's in the main page. You'll only get a scroll bar in the DIV if its contents are too big to fit, but you only have one line of content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because there is no content force it to actually scroll anything.

Here I added an inner `div`, which is higher, and make it scrollable.

Stack snippet

```js
document.querySelector('.test-scroll')
  .addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    alert('Scroll');
  }, false);
```

```css
.test-scroll {
  height: 2000px;
  overflow-x: none;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.test-scroll div {
  height: 3000px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-scroll">

<div></div>

</div>
```